# Xcode Project Comparison Tool

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, svn, project-management

I facing a problem, on tracking changes made by other developers.

Note: SVN is not used for some reasons.

So, is there any better way apart from individual file comparison using [kDiff](http://kdiff3.sourceforge.net/%22kDiff%22). This is too tiresome for large number of files.

Such as looking for entire Project's Comparison, for projects created in Xcode.

Thanks.

Comment: Not using source code control is insane. Stop now and fix this before anyone writes one more line of code. I work alone and I use source code control. With multiple devs it is mandatory.

Comment: @rmaddy, you are right. I do use svn but, due some unavoidable reason we are not able to use SVN for a particular project.

Comment: Then use git. I can't think of any reason that would prevent the use of a source code control system.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use *FileMerge* that comes as part of the Xcode package. This will take two directories and compare the contents of the trees rooted at that point showing files only in one tree, that differ in the two trees, etc. For differing files you get a standard visual diff. This should give you what you need quickly and easily, we actually use it in conjunction with svn to compare branches, check merges, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use *any other* SCM, it's a **natural way** of tracking changes ("Source Control...")

If you still want make own life harder, you can use *any* OS-specific tool, which can compare directories, not only separate files